# How To Sum all the values of a column for a date instance in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, data-analysis

I am working on time-series data, where I have two columns date and quantity. The date is day wise. I want to add all the quantity for a month and convert it into a single date.

**date is my index column**

Example

```
         quantity
date
2018-01-03   30
2018-01-05   45
2018-01-19   30
2018-02-09   10
2018-02-19   20
```

Output :

```
          quantity
date
2018-01-01   105
2018-02-01   30
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: ``df.resample("M").sum()``. FIrst ensure the date is in the right form : ``df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can downsample to combine the data for each month and sum it by chaining the sum method.

`df.resample("M").sum()`

Check out the pandas user guide on resampling [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling).

You'll need to make sure your index is in datetime format for this to work. So first do: `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`. Hat tip to sammywemmy for the same advice in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You an also use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to get results.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-01')).sum()
```

[image]